# Facebook error 2FA

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

## Facebook sdk - help me to solve

### I have integrated all of things in my facebook developer account

ErrorUtils caught an error

```
  <![EX[["Bootloader: %s is not in the component map" GeneratedArtilleryUserTi.... Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

reportError

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'appID',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.8'
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
            console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
            console.log(e);

            if (e.event == 'rendered') {
                console.log("Plugin was rendered");
            } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
                var checkboxState = e.state;
                console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
            } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
                console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
            } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
                console.log("Plugin was hidden");
            }
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    );
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what error you're getting and at what stage/code?

Comment: signup:40 Plugin was hidden. This usually means a problem in FB or integration... Did you whitelist your domain? When using a FB dev app is your FB account registered developer/tester/admin? Have generated a unique `user_ref` for this render? And maybe more...

Comment: Error : <![EX[["Bootloader: %s is not in the component map" GeneratedArtilleryUserTi.... Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.